# Unfortunately the app has stopped

Tags: android, apache, crash

I am trying to make a login register app but when I open register activity it crashes.
I cant seem to figure out whats the problem I followed the same steps in the tutorial series given https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4VTi5-Aw20
following is my code:
Register.java:
package com.mohd.loginre;

```
    import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;


        public class Register extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

        EditText user=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.rusername);
        EditText pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.rpassword);
        EditText ag=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.rage);
        Button rsubmit;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
            rsubmit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.rsubmit);
            rsubmit.setOnClickListener( this);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.getId()==R.id.rsubmit){
                String username=user.getText().toString();
                String password=pass.getText().toString();
                int age=Integer.parseInt(ag.getText().toString());
                User user=new User(username,password,age);
                registerhim(user);
            }
        }

        private void registerhim(User user) {
            ServerRequests serverRequest=new ServerRequests(this);
            serverRequest.storeUserDataInBackground(user, new GetUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(User returnedUser) {
                    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(Register.this, Login.class);
                    startActivity(loginIntent);
                }
            });


        }
    }




    ServerRequests.java

    package com.mohd.loginre;

    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.util.Log;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
    import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
    import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class ServerRequests {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        public static final int Timeout = 1000 * 15;
        public static final String server = "http://mohdgadi.netai.net/";
    public ServerRequests(Context context) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Processing...");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    }

    public void storeUserDataInBackground(User user,
                                          GetUserCallback userCallBack) {
        progressDialog.show();
        new StoreUserDataAsyncTask(user, userCallBack).execute();
    }

    public void fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallBack) {
        progressDialog.show();
        new fetchUserDataAsyncTask(user, userCallBack).execute();
    }

    /**
     * parameter sent to task upon execution progress published during
     * background computation result of the background computation
     */

    public class StoreUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        User user;
        GetUserCallback userCallBack;

        public StoreUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallBack) {
            this.user = user;
            this.userCallBack = userCallBack;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", user.age + ""));

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = getHttpRequestParams();

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(server
                    + "Register.php");

            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                client.execute(post);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        private HttpParams getHttpRequestParams() {
            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                   Timeout);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                    Timeout);
            return httpRequestParams;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            userCallBack.done(null);
        }

    }

    public class fetchUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User> {
        User user;
        GetUserCallback userCallBack;

        public fetchUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallBack) {
            this.user = user;
            this.userCallBack = userCallBack;
        }

        @Override
        protected User doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                    Timeout);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                    Timeout);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(server
                    + "FetchUserData.php");

            User returnedUser = null;

            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

                if (jObject.length() != 0){
                    Log.v("happened", "2");
                    String name = jObject.getString("name");
                    int age = jObject.getInt("age");

                    returnedUser = new User(user.username,
                            user.password,age);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return returnedUser;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User returnedUser) {
            super.onPostExecute(returnedUser);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            userCallBack.done(returnedUser);
        }
    }
}
```

I dont get any errors during compiling I tried this on emulator as well as my android device but same error.Please help!!

Answer (score 2):

Move

```
EditText user=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.rusername);
EditText pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.rpassword);
EditText ag=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.rage);
```

inside `onCreate(..)` after  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);`

Comment: Thanks alot this helped,register activity now opens but now when I fill the input fields and submit it crashes instead of opening login activity.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
 Button rsubmit;
 EditText user,pass,ag;

     @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
                rsubmit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.rsubmit);

                user=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.rusername);
                pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.rpassword);
                ag=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.rage);


                rsubmit.setOnClickListener( this);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks alot this helped,register activity now opens but now when I fill the input fields and submit it crashes instead of opening login activity.

Comment: I'll take a guess - is your Login activity listed in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: DeviceMonitor: Adb rejected connection to client '1938': closed
DeviceMonitor: Adb rejected connection to client '2365': closed
DeviceMonitor: Adb rejected connection to client '2365': closed

but this was even there before u solved the register activity problem

@TommySM yes its there in manifest

Comment: Try killing and restarting your adb. `adb kill-server` & `adb start-server`

Comment: No effect i even tried running it in my phone but same